# Which is better: deque or list slicing?

Tags: python, performance, slice, deque

If I use the code

```
from collections import deque
q = deque(maxlen=2)
while step <= step_max:
    calculate(item)
    q.append(item)
    another_calculation(q)
```

how does it compare in efficiency and readability to

```
q = []
while step <= step_max:
    calculate(item)
    q.append(item)
    q = q[-2:]
    another_calculation(q)
```

`calculate()` and `another_calculation()` are not real in this case but in my actual program are simply two calculations. I'm doing these calculations every step for millions of steps (I'm simulating an ion in 2-d space). Because there are so many steps, `q` gets very long and uses a lot of memory, while `another_calculation()` only uses the last two values of `q`. I had been using the latter method, then heard `deque` mentioned and thought it might be more efficient; thus the question.

I.e., how do deques in python compare to just normal list slicing?

Comment: @timgeb I can do the timings, but I don't know why something is faster or slower. I learn more by asking the question. Anyway, sorry that I didn't ask a good enough question.

Comment: The fastest way is, to create a list with one element: `q = [item]`. So it depends, on what you really want to do, which solution is best.

Comment: @Daniel I will be adding multiple elements to the list; I was just illustrating how it would be used.

Comment: @heather: show a real example, currently, it is useless.

Comment: @Daniel updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q = q[-2:]
```

now this is a costly operation because it recreates a list everytime (and copies the references). (A nasty side effect here is that it changes the reference of `q` even if you can use `q[:] = q[-2:]` to avoid that).

The `deque` object just changes the start of the list pointer and "forgets" the oldest item. So it's faster and it's one of the usages it's been designed for.

Of course, for 2 values, there isn't much difference, but for a bigger number there is.

Comment: I did some quick timing, and the deque approach is already faster when appending 4 items (and just a little bit slower with 2 or 3 items). For large numbers of values, using the deque is about 3 times faster.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks. I suspect that list slicing is so optimized that with a small value, it can beat the overhead of the deque.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille so with my use, which needs only two values, list slicing would be better? Or are they comparable (in which case, is one more accepted/more readable)?

Comment: on those limit cases, you have to time both, and choose the fastest. But be careful that noone needs to increase the value, which would make the code slower (leave a big "warning" comment about this). The fastest may not be the same depending on the machine & python version.

Comment: @heather I did the timing with queues of length 2. It gets worse for list slicing when the queue gets longer: for a queue of length 1000, the list slicing is 50 times slower than the deque.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you have a function, that calculates a value, and you want to do another calculation with this and the previous value. The best way is to use two variables:

```
while step <= step_max:
    item = calculate()
    another_calculation(previous_item, item)
    previous_item = item
```

If the calculations are some form of vector math, you should consider using numpy.